# Why does setting the range of cells to read in read_xlsb yield the error Error in is.null(range) || is.na(range)?

Tags: r, xlsb

I am trying to read a (large) xlsb file in R. Given the size of the file, I am reading it in groups of lines. However, I always run in trouble at some point.
For instance, the following code:

```
  Df <- read_xlsb("C:/MyData.xlsb", 
                         sheet = "mysheet" , 
                          range = cellranger::cell_limits(c(1, 1), c(100000, NA)) , 
                         col_names = TRUE )
```

yields the error message

```
Error in is.null(range) || is.na(range) : 
  'length = 3' in coercion to 'logical(1)'
```

Alternatively,

```
  Df  <- read_xlsb("C:/MyData.xlsb", 
                         sheet = "My_sheet" , 
                         range = "A1:BC1500000",
                         col_names = TRUE )
```

yields

```
Error: Cell references aren't uniformly A1 or R1C1 format:
A1:BC1500000
In addition: Warning message:
Cell reference follows neither the A1 nor R1C1 format. Example:
BC1500000
NAs generated.
```

I have installed the most recent version of readxlsb and cellranger. Note that the second error does not occur for smaller ranges, such as A1:BC1500.

Comment: That's a bug in the `read_xlsb` function.  `is.na(range)` returns a vector of the same length as `range`, and that's not allowed in the condition for an if statement.  The maintainer of whatever package provided that function should fix it.

Comment: Thank you, I have signalled it to the package maintainer. Are there alternative approaches to load large xlsb files? I have also tried excel.link but then I get the error message "Error: Not enough memory resources are available to complete this operation."

Comment: I don't know much about .xlsb files.  Maybe you could save in a different format, e.g. csv.  I think `read.csv` will be slow for a big file, but `readr::read_csv` might be faster.